# How to add Error Bar to Matplotlib line plot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following dataset which I use to plot a line plot. The plot is obtained as the `mean` of values obtained from the data. I want to add error bars to this plot which shall show the standard deviation. I have looked up to different answers but in most of them they had defined `x` and `y` explicitly, but here I calculate the plot directly from the dataframe. How to add error bar to this plot?

**Dataframe df**

```
UserId     |   date                 |-7|-6|-5|-4|-3|-2|-1|0 |1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |6 |7
     1      2009-10-17 17:38:32.590 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0  
     2      2009-10-19 00:37:23.067 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |1 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0    
     3      2009-10-20 08:37:14.143 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 
     4      2009-10-21 18:07:51.247 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 
     5      2009-10-22 21:25:24.483 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0
```

**Code**

```
badges = ["A", "B", "C"]

for badge in badges:
  res.iloc[:,2:].mean().plot(kind='line', label = badge)
```

**Output**

[image: Output Obtained]

Answer (score 0):

Why not compute the `x` values explicitly? In the dataframe above,

```
x = [c for c in res.columns() if isinstance(int, c)]
```

Then, the code can be as follows.

```
badges = ["A", "B", "C"]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for badge in badges:
    means = res.iloc[:,2:].mean()
    std = res.iloc[:, 2:].std()
    means.plot(kind='line', label = badge)

    ax.plot(means)
    ax.fill_between(x, means.sub(std), means.add(std), color='b', alpha=.1)
```

Note: In the code above, you use `badges` only in the plot. Maybe computing means and std should be done outside the cycle? I am not sure because your sample data frame above does not have badges.